# C program with linked list to add/delete integers & calculate avg

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, insert

I am trying to modify this code to add new numbers to the list with symbol "+" and delete with symbol "-". If the number entered is even, it should insert the number at the start of the list, if its odd, it should insert it at the end. The program will end after 0 (+0 or -0) is entered. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
} node;

node * insert(node *head, int num)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = num;

    if (head == NULL || head->data > num)
    {
        temp->ptr = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *current = head;
        while ((current->ptr != NULL) && !(num < current->ptr->data))

        {
            current = current->ptr;
        }

        temp->ptr = current->ptr;
        current->ptr = temp;
    }

    return head;
}

node * delete_if_less( node *head, int data )
{
    while ( head != NULL && head->data < data )
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->ptr;
        free( temp );
    }

    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        for ( node *current = head; current->ptr != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->ptr->data < data )
            {
                node *temp = current->ptr;
                current->ptr = current->ptr->ptr;
                free( temp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void free_list(node *head) {
    node *prev = head;
    node *cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = prev->ptr;
        free(prev);
    }
}

int main(){
    int num, min;
    node *head, *p;
    head = NULL;

    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if(num) {
            head = insert(head, num);
            for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->ptr )
            {
                printf("%d ", p->data);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while(num);

    p = head;
    printf("\nThe entered numbers are:\n");

    while(p) {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->ptr;
    }
    free_list(head);


    head = delete_if_less( head, num );

    if ( num != 0 ) {
       printf( "There are deleted %zu nodes.\n", num );
    }

    printf("\nEnter minimum: ");
    scanf("%d", & min);

    return 0;
}
```

I want it then to calculate 1) the sum of all added integers 2) the sum of all deleted integers 3) the total sum of the remaining numbers of the list 4) the number of integers left and 5) the arithmetic average of the remaining numbers. The input should look like something like this:

```
Enter +/- to add/del a number: +1
1 
Enter +/- to add/del a number: +2
2 1
Enter +/- to add/del a number: +3
2 1 3 
Enter +/- to add/del a number: +1
2 1 3 1
Enter +/- to add/del a number: +5
2 1 3 1 5
Enter +/- to add/del a number: -4
Numbers not in list.
2 1 3 1 5
Enter +/- to add/del a number: -3
2 1 1 5
Enter +/- to add/del a number: -1
2 1 5
Enter +/- to add/del a number: +0
2 1 5

add sum: 13
del sum: 5
total sum: 8
elements: 3
average: 2.67
```

Can anyone help me with this? I would appreciate it alot. :)

Comment: You continue to operate on the list after you've freed it. That's not going to en well.

Comment: Please read this: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2027196)

Comment: *"Can anyone help me "* What do you need help with? Please be specific as to what your problems are.

Comment: Apparenly there are also bugs in `delete_if_less`, and when you call `delete_if_less(head, num)`, `num` is always 0, and by definition there are no 0 values in the list, so even if `delete_if_less` had no bugs, nothing would be deleted from the liste here. You need to debug this, it's pretty simple. A piece of paper and a pencil will be valuable tools for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach to your code!

I used linked lists with a sentinel to optimize a bit. Also since in your example you wanted to keep the information about the deleted values, there are actually two linked lists in the program, one for **present** values, and another for **bin** values.

It works exactly as you have described in the input section,though I have added several more functionalities.

Here are the possible inputs:
in each of them n is an integer from 0 to 9

**+on** -> adds n to a linked list

**-on** -> deletes n from a linked list if it exists, if n not present prints an error message

**-an** -> deletes all occurrences of n from a linked list, if n not present prints an error message

**+m** -> deletes the maximum of a linked list

**-m** -> deletes the minimum of a linked list

**0** -> terminates the function

Of course you could parse it differently to include larger int values but I guess I will leave that part to you!

At each operation the two linked lists will be printed out on the terminal so you can see the result of your operation and the current state of the two lists. If your message did not match the parsing, an error will be raised and will be printed on the terminal. Same goes for deleting a value that does not exist in the linked list.

After entering **0** the program will calculate different properties of the list based on what you have asked in your example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Prints a string of characters.
static inline void print(const char* f, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, f);
    vprintf(f, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// Prints a string of characters followed by a new line.
static inline void println(const char* f, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, f);
    vprintf(f, args);
    va_end(args);
    printf("\n");
}

static inline void* mem_alloc(size_t size)
{
    void* p = malloc(size);

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Problem with malloc().");
    }
    return p;
}



// Verify if node is empty 
int node_is_empty(node * head)
{
    return head == NULL;
}

// Verify if node is not empty 
int node_is_not_empty(node * head)
{
    return head != NULL;
}

//Builds the sentinell of the node structure

node* node_build_sentinel()
{
    // Creates the sentinel.
    node* head = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    head->value = 0;
    head->next = NULL;


    // Returns the head of the node which is the sentinell.
    return head;
}

//Prints the contents of a node 
void node_print(node* head)
{
    print("{");
    while(head->next)
    {
        head = head->next;
        print(" %d", head->value);
    }
    println(" }");
}

//Frees the allocated node
void node_free(node* head)
{
    node* previous;

    while (head)
    {
        previous = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(previous);
    }
}

// Inserts a value right after the head
/*

    HEAD -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8 
    node_insert_beg(node* HEAD, int 42);
    HEAD -> 42 -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8

*/
void node_insert_beg(node* head, int value)
{
    node* tmp = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = head->next;
    head->next = tmp;
}

// Inserts a value right after the head
/*

    HEAD -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8 
    node_insert_end(node* HEAD, int 42);
    HEAD -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8 -> 42

*/
void node_insert_end(node* head, int value)
{
    node* tmp = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    for (; node_is_not_empty(head->next); head = head->next)
    {
        //This loop runs to the last node and quits with head being that last node
        continue;
    }
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = head->next;
    head->next = tmp;
}

//Inserts odd values to the end and even values to the beginning
void node_insert_num(node* head, int value)
{
    //odd
    if(value % 2)
    {
        node_insert_end(head, value);
    }
    //even
    else
    {
        node_insert_beg(head, value);
    }
}

//Extracts the minimum value of the node (in other words deletes it from the node)
void node_extract_min(node* list,node *sup)
{
    node *before_min = list;
    while (list->next != NULL)
    {
        if (list->next->value < before_min->next->value)
        {
            before_min = list;
        }   
        list = list->next;
    }
    node *output = before_min->next;
    before_min->next = before_min->next->next;
    output->next = NULL;
    while (sup->next!=NULL)
    {
        sup = sup->next;
    }
    sup->next = output;
}


//Extracts the maximum value of the node (in other words deletes it from the node)
void node_extract_max(node* list, node* sup)
{
    node *before_max = list;
    while (list->next != NULL)
    {
        if (list->next->value > before_max->next->value)
        {
            before_max = list;
        }   
        list = list->next;
    }
    node *output = before_max->next;
    before_max->next = before_max->next->next;
    output->next = NULL;
    while (sup->next!=NULL)
    {
        sup = sup->next;
    }
    sup->next = output;
}

//Deletes the first occurence of value in node
int node_delete_first_occurence(node* head, node* sup, int value)
{
    int seen = 0;
    node *tmp = head;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        if (head->next->value == value)
        {
            tmp = head;
            seen+=1;
            break;
        }   
        head = head->next;
    }
    if(seen == 0)
    {
        return seen;
    }
    node *output = head->next;
    tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
    output->next = NULL;
    while (sup->next!=NULL)
    {
        sup = sup->next;
    }
    sup->next = output;
    return seen;
}

//Deletes all occurences of value in node
int node_delete_all_occurences(node* head, node* sup, int value)
{
    int seen = 0;
    node *tmp = head;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        if (head->next->value == value)
        {
            seen+=1;
            tmp = head;
            node *output = head->next;
            tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
            output->next = NULL;
            while (sup->next!=NULL)
            {
                sup = sup->next;
            }
            sup->next = output;
            continue;
        } 
        head = head->next;
    }
    return seen;
}

//Get a node at index if index invalid return NULL
//DOES NOT DELETE THE NODE
node * node_get_at(node* node, unsigned long index)
{
    while (node != NULL && index > 0)
    {
        node = node->next;
        index--;
    }
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        node = node->next;
    }
    return node;
}

int* node_sum(node * head)
{
    int * sum_elem = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    int sum = 0;
    int elements = 0;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        elements+=1;
        sum += head->next->value;
        head = head->next;
    }
    sum_elem[0] = sum;
    sum_elem[1] = elements;
    return sum_elem;
}


int main()
{
    node * present_node = node_build_sentinel();
    node * deleted_nodes = node_build_sentinel();
    char message[4];
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter +/- followed by type (o = one/a = all/m = min or max) followed by the number to add/del a number or 0 to quit the app:");
        scanf("%3s",message);
        if(message[0] == '+')
        {
            if(message[1] == 'o')
            {
                node_insert_num(present_node,message[2] - '0');
                node_print(present_node);
                node_print(deleted_nodes);
                continue;
            }
            if(message[1] == 'm')
            {
                node_extract_max(present_node,deleted_nodes);
                node_print(present_node);
                node_print(deleted_nodes);
                continue;
            }
            if(message[1] == 'a')
            {
                printf("Invalid syntax on opperand 2 after + (no a is possible) please try again!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid syntax on opperand 2 after + please try again!\n");
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(message[0] == '-')
        {
            if(message[1] == 'o')
            {
                int err = node_delete_first_occurence(present_node,deleted_nodes,message[2] - '0');
                if(err == 0)
                {
                    printf("The number to delete was not present in the node!\n");
                }
                node_print(present_node);
                node_print(deleted_nodes);
                continue;
            }
            if(message[1] == 'a')
            {
                int err = node_delete_all_occurences(present_node,deleted_nodes,message[2] - '0');
                if(err == 0)
                {
                    printf("The number to delete was not present in the node!\n");
                }
                node_print(present_node);
                node_print(deleted_nodes);
                continue;
            }
            if(message[1] == 'm')
            {
                node_extract_min(present_node,deleted_nodes);
                node_print(present_node);
                node_print(deleted_nodes);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid syntax on opperand 2 after - please try again!\n");
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(message[0] == '0')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid syntax on opperand 1 please try again!\n");
        }
        
    }


    int * present_sum_elem = node_sum(present_node);
    printf("The sum of present node: %d \n",present_sum_elem[0]);
    printf("The number of elements in present node: %d\n",present_sum_elem[1]);
    if(present_sum_elem[1]!=0)
    {
        printf("The average of the present node %4f \n", (float)present_sum_elem[0]/(float)present_sum_elem[1]);
    }
    
    
    int * deleted_sum_elem = node_sum(deleted_nodes);
    printf("The sum of deleted node: %d \n",deleted_sum_elem[0]);
    printf("The number of elements in deleted node: %d\n",deleted_sum_elem[1]);
    if(deleted_sum_elem[1] != 0)
    {
        printf("The average of the deleted node %4f \n", (float)deleted_sum_elem[0]/(float)deleted_sum_elem[1]);
    }

    free(present_sum_elem);
    free(deleted_sum_elem);
    node_free(present_node);
    node_free(deleted_nodes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, brother that was helpful... I will try to formulate my questions better next time. But thank you :)